# bash script Keyboard Interrupt hand over to Python Script

Tags: python, python-3.x, bash, shell

I have a bash script that starts my python script. Point of this is, that I hand over a lot of (sometimes changing) arguments to the python script. So I found it useful to start my python script with a bash script where I "save" my argument list.

```
#!/bin/bash
cd $(dirname $0)
python3 script.py [arg0] [arg1]
```

In my Python script I have the KeyboardInterrupt-Exception implemented which would save some open files and then exit the python script.
Now my question: When I run the shell script I have to at least press 3-times Strg+C, get some python errors and it will stop.

Am i guessing right, that my Strg+C is not recognized by python, but by the shell script instead?
Is there a way to hand over the Keyboard Interrupt from the shell script to the python script running in it?

btw: the python script is running an infinite loop (if this is important)

Python script looks like this for the exception. As pointed out, it runs an infinite loop.

```
    while True:
        try:
            #doing stuff here

        except KeyboardInterrupt:
            for file in files:
                file.close()
            break
```

Comment: Please provide the handling exception code

Answer (score 1):

If that's your entire script, why not tail-call `python`?  Bash will get completely out of the way.

```
#!/bin/bash
cd $(dirname $0)
exec python3 script.py [arg0] [arg1]
```

Comment: this worked for me, after I had tried `trap 'kill -INT %1 %2' INT` and fussing around with this for a long time in the python context before it occurred to me that python was never seeing the kill signal.  I wonder what are the drawbacks of using the "tail-call" with python?

Answer (score 0):

try "trap" command to assign custom action on signals. For Ctrl-C you need to ignore  SIGINT, also you can ignore SIGTERM:

```
function ignore_ctrlc() {
        echo "ignored"
}

trap ignore_ctrlc SIGINT SIGTERM
declare -i counter=0
while true; do
  echo "sleep for 1 sec"
  sleep 1
  counter+=1
  [[ $counter -gt 10 ]] && exit 0
done
```

In the script above, Ctrl-C will interrupt executing command (most probability it will be sleep 1), but will not interrupt the script itself. In your case, your python script should ignore Ctrl-C, so I think it will be ignored at all.